# converting numbers to degree

Tags: elementary-number-theory, numerical-methods

I have **0 to 1 that represent 0 to 360 degrees** I know that **0.5 would represent 180 degrees** but what formula would I use to get the other vales for 0 to 1.

Thanks

Comment: Multiply or divide by $360$, depending on which way you wish to convert.

Comment: It's a simple scaling - if your input is $N$, you probably need $N\times 360$. Check parity and offset though, you might have angle measured in opposite directions or from a different reference point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the simple formula

$$ \mbox{Original Degree} \div 360$$

As you said 180 is 0.5, you got this since $180 \div 360=0.5$

For example 90 degress is $90 \div 360=0.25$

Answer (score 1):

$1\Rightarrow360\deg$

$x\Rightarrow y\ \deg$

Thus, for $x\in[0;1]$, $y\deg=\frac{x\times 360\deg}{1}$

As for converting from $y$ $\deg$s to $x\in[0;1]$,

$x=\frac{y\deg\times1}{360\deg}$

All of this can be seen directly, but I simplified as much as possible, using the old "arrows" method of proportionality. (Not sure what we used to call it.)